# Boolean method doesn't work like it should

Tags: java

So I really don't get what I did wrong here. The method should take a boolean array and check if all elements are true, if one is false it should return false.

```
public static boolean nvm(boolean[] con) {
    boolean c = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < con.length ; i++) {
        if (and(con[i], con[i++]) == false) {
            c = false;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

The `and` check two booleans, if they're both true it returns true, otherwhise false. I have already tested `and`, but its working fine.

Wrote the post on my mobile, so I hope it doesn't looks weird. Thankful for any help.

Comment: add `break;` just after setting `c=false;`

Comment: I wonder how much time you've spent by thinking about the usage of `i++`. Does this code really makes sense to you?

Comment: What do you suggest ?

Comment: I suggest you think about what `i++` is and what it does.

Comment: Doesn't work with `break;` either. I take [true,true,false,true] as testarray and it returns true, while it should return false.

Comment: i++ <=> i = i + 1.  Still doesn't get what's the problem with that

Comment: Very surprised you get any result at all; I'd have expected an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: `i++ <=> I=I+1`:. not so much a problem in your `for` statement; becomes a problem when you do it _again_ inside the loop

Comment: Ye I got it, didn't realize that the `i++` would affect the `i` because I just use it as an index

Comment: Not only that, `con[i],con[i++]` makes also no sense. And no, `i++` is not the same as `i = i + 1`.

Comment: @IPiiro So why did you write it then? This is rather basic.

Comment: Didn't use java for a long time and was just refreshing my knowledge.

Comment: @Tom so where is exactly the difference between i++ and i = i + 1 ?

Comment: The result (or returned value) is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
if(and(con[i],con[i++]) == false){
```

Particularly with `i++` part. `i++` actually increases i, so you may skip some array elements and get a wrong result. Use `i+1` instead, which would leave `i` unchanged.

Also, you can simplify your code like this:

```
public static boolean nvm(boolean[] con) {
    for(int i = 0; i < con.length ; i++) {
        if (!con[i]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Oh but I didn't realize this `i++` "really" affects the i as the counter

Answer (score 2):

> The method should take a boolean array and check if all elements are
>   true

```
for(int i = 0; i<con.length ; i++){
     if(!con[i]) return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow.. that is so damn obvious... I guess I'm still asleep :D

Comment: @BackSlash No, it most certainly is not.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but

> 'The method should take a boolean array and check if all elements are true, if one is false it should return false'

can be written as:

```
boolean[] array;
for(boolean a : array) {
  if(!a) { return false; }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you you want to check that all elements are true you can easily simplify your code.

```
public static boolean nvm(boolean[] con) {
    for(int i = 0; i<con.length ; i++) {
        If(!con[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I do not see any reason for the "and". I can only see that it may cause you to have an idexoutofboundsexception.